# Replace FxCop with Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: code-analysis, fxcop

Currently we are using FxCop for code analysis in our project.

But we need to replace FxCop with Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2015.

Is there a way we can do so?

Thanks.

Comment: kind of vague.  do you mean in the msbuild steps?

Comment: Currently we are using FxCop file for code analysis but in VS 2015 we have Code Analysis feature. So we need to replace FxCop with VS 2015 Code Analysis

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert your own custom FxCop rules to Analyzers? or you mean you want to replace standard/third party FxCop rules with equivalent analyzers? If the former, then you need to provide a lot more detail on what it's doing, if the latter then you need to specify which one (and be aware that not all FxCop rules have analyzer equivalents)